# URLRequest equality doesn't include httpBody

Tags: swift, urlrequest, swift4.2

### Overview

There are 2 `URLRequest`s, one with `httpBody` and one with no `httpBody`.
However when compared, it shows both are equal.

### Question

Is this expected behaviour or am I missing something ?

### Code

```
let url = URL(string: "www.somevalidURL.com")!

var r1 = URLRequest(url: url)
r1.addValue("Content-Type", forHTTPHeaderField: "application/json; charset=utf-8")
r1.httpBody = makeBody(withParameters: ["email" : "a@b.com"])

var r2 = URLRequest(url: url)
r2.addValue("Content-Type", forHTTPHeaderField: "application/json; charset=utf-8")

if r1 == r2 {
    print("requests are equal")
}
else {
    print("requests are not equal")
}

if r1.httpBody == r2.httpBody {
    print("body is equal")
}
else {
    print("body is not equal")
}

func makeBody(withParameters bodyParameters: [String : Any]?) -> Data? {
    guard let bodyParameters = bodyParameters,
        !bodyParameters.isEmpty else {
            return nil
    }
    let body : Data?
    do {
        body = try JSONSerialization.data(withJSONObject: bodyParameters,
                                          options: .prettyPrinted)
    }
    catch {
        print("Error in creating Web Service Body = \(error)")
        body = nil
    }
    return body
}
```

### Output

```
requests are equal
body is not equal
```

---

<sub>Xcode 10

Swift Version: 4.2</sub>

Comment: So `== (lhs:, rhs:)` checks only the equality of the `url` property? Check also with different headers?

Comment: See updated question, when I compare requests it says it is equal, however when I compare `httpBody` it says it is not equal

Comment: I'm saying it depends on how Apple implemented the `==` method. If they don't care about the body, but just the url, then they are equals. But what are the criteria to define equal?

Comment: Fair point, I was using it in some of the test cases, probably will have to manually compare the `httpBody`

Comment: You can use your own `URLRequest` if that's important for you, derivating it, and implementing your own comparing method including the HTTB body, or simply having a custom method `func isCustomEqual(to other: URLRequest) { return self.httpBody == other.httpBody && self == other }`? and use that one.

Comment: For my requirement, I would just additional comparison for `httpBody`

Answer (score 12, accepted):

`URLRequest` is the Swift overlay type for the Foundation type `NSURLRequest`, so that that `==` ultimately calls the `isEqual()` method of
the `NSURLRequest`.

The Foundation library is open source for non-Apple platforms, and at
[NSURLRequest.swift#L252](https://github.com/apple/swift-corelibs-foundation/blob/main/Sources/FoundationNetworking/NSURLRequest.swift#L252) we find:

```
open override func isEqual(_ object: Any?) -> Bool {
    //On macOS this fields do not determine the result:
    //allHTTPHeaderFields
    //timeoutInterval
    //httBody
    //networkServiceType
    //httpShouldUsePipelining
    guard let other = object as? NSURLRequest else { return false }
    return other === self
        || (other.url == self.url
            && other.mainDocumentURL == self.mainDocumentURL
            && other.httpMethod == self.httpMethod
            && other.cachePolicy == self.cachePolicy
            && other.httpBodyStream == self.httpBodyStream
            && other.allowsCellularAccess == self.allowsCellularAccess
            && other.httpShouldHandleCookies == self.httpShouldHandleCookies)
```

So that seems to be intentional.

Comment: Almost reached here. I was reading about the `isEqual` method. :D

Comment: Cool explanation, I suppose I would add additional `XCTAssertEqual` for the httpBody and would fit my needs.

Comment: The correct URL is https://github.com/apple/swift-corelibs-foundation/blob/main/Sources/FoundationNetworking/NSURLRequest.swift#L252

Comment: @Andrew: Thanks for letting me know, I have updated the link.

Comment: I found out that sometimes the httpBody is different event when it's created based on the same JSON dict. The order of items is different - so maybe that is the reason why isEqual is not compering them.

Answer (score 0):

If you've come here wondering why your identical `URLRequest`s aren't equal to each other like I did I found the reason to be that *`URLRequest`'s equatable implementation differentiates between `httpBody` being set to nil or being defaulting to nil.*

If we do the following:

```
let request = URLRequest(url: URL(string: "test.com"))
var expectedRequest = URLRequest(url: URL(string: "test.com"))
expectedRequest.httpBody = nil
```

Then:

```
request == expectedRequest //false
print(request.httpBody) // nil
request.httpBody = nil
request == expectedRequest //true
```

Explicitly settings the `httpBody` to `nil` will fix this issue. In fact what the body is doesn't matter, only that it has been explicitly set.

```
request.httpBody = Data()
request == expectedRequest //true
```

---

**Potential explanation**

As Martin rightly points out [Swift's source code](https://github.com/apple/swift-corelibs-foundation/blob/master/Foundation/NSURLRequest.swift#L245) does not include httpBody. However all of the properties (in the link) being equal (and both being castable as NSURLRequests) does not return `true` (see lldb output below). I can only presume the linked code is overridden to include another property and this is modified when `didSet` or `willSet` is called on `httpBody`
[image: lldb Terminal Log]